# Which GUI tookit for quick working prototypes/mockups

Tags: user-interface, prototype, mockups

I'm primarily a server-side developer - not even web server stuff.  But I'm finding more and more that I need to mockup user interfaces.  This is in part to more senior roles doing overall product design, but there is some personal interest as well.

I'm wondering what would be a good UI toolkit to learn.  I won't be making production user interfaces, and doing them as web apps would just be fine.  I've been leaning towards learning jQuery as it has a graphing library I like to use (flot).  Someone else at work is suggesting EXT-GWT.

Is there anything else out there?  For straight up mockups I use Balsamiq, but sometimes I want to go a little past plain mockups and add some functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  For this particular task I went to JQuery and JQuery mobile.  Not sure if I like Javascript for a long lived project, but this got my concept out which is all I really need to do.  GWT would be my second choice, and perhaps my first choice for a more formal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used anything a lot except jQuery.

It has been great especially when you start using the UI and theming which makes quick work of standard things. It'd be a problem if you wanted anything outside the box because then you'd have to find a plugin or write your own. (both of which are fairly easy IMHO.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after GUI libraries/frameworks, have a look at [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) and [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home).

You might want to also look at something like [WaveMaker](http://dev.wavemaker.com/), which is a rapid application development platform. As well as allowing you to mock up simple GUI's it should make it easy to add in functionality as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ExtJS, they also have a designer: http://www.sencha.com/products/designer

Even if you just go with ExtJS, Senchas has a lot of widgets that make prototyping much easier.  ExtJS 4 will be shipping in a month or so. I'd start with it.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0-beta3/examples/

Comment: They also have stencils now for some graphics programs.

https://www.sencha.com/blog/wireframing-made-easy-with-ext-js-stencils/

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com). It makes working prototype and run as DHTML in browser.  It's quite easy to learn and use.